# Xcode: 'No such module' - after pulling project from Git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

**The problem:**

We had a build on the App Store which worked perfectly, then I pulled the same commit from the Git, and the compiler was constantly alerting some missing modules. This was weird cause all of the modules were there, no change was made, and on the machine (device) of my colleague wasn't showing any error.

The error is:

> No such module 'NameOfModule'

Firstly it started to show on:

```
import IdensicMobileSDK
```

After a few *Cleans of Build Folder*, it's not showing any more on that part.
Now is showing on:

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_FilledTextFields
```

This is happening on my machine (device) after pulling it from Git, on my colleague's machine (device) is working great (running and building without any errors).

**What steps I took to fix it:**

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Delete Xcode
3. Delete Cocoapods on Mac
4. Delete Git
5. Delete Homebrew
6. Re-install everything

None of them worked. Only `pod install` fixed this error, but it modified some Pod files and caused other errors. It was weird why it modified Pod files when nothing was changed.

Just in case you need to see the Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/SumSubstance/Specs.git'

target 'project' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for project

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.12.0'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', '~> 3.4.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '~> 7.6.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 7.6.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 7.6.0'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 7.6.0'
    pod 'MaterialComponents'
    pod 'lottie-ios', '~> 3.1.8'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 6.5.5'
    pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
    pod 'SwiftLint', '~> 0.40.1'
    pod 'UPCarouselFlowLayout', '~> 1.1.2'
    pod 'SOPullUpView', '~> 1.1.0'
    pod 'PieCharts', '~> 0.0.7'
    pod 'IdensicMobileSDK'
    pod 'TagListView', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'DropDown'
    pod 'MnemonicSwift'

  target 'project-iosTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'project-iosUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you run pod update before pod install?

Comment: Also because you dont have locked versions when you run a pod update it will update those sdks to the latest version so yes those pod files will change.

Comment: Do you commit your pods to your repo?  I don't, but I know that some do. If your pods aren't in your repo then you would need to perform a `pod update` or `pod install` after checking out a new copy of the repo

Comment: @Aggressor I ran `pod update` but it didn't fix that. 

Also, my colleague ran it and pushed it immediately to Git, I pulled it and the issue occured. So it was in just a couple of minutes, no change was made to the frameworks we are using. To mention again, we made not a single change on the project, it was weird how files changed after `pod install`.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes we do (please suggest alternatives, like some documentations or something).

I ran `pod update` it didn't fix the error, it kept the same error plus it added more errors. `pod install` fixed the error, but it's adding the same errors as `pod update`. Those errors are making unable to build it to the App Store.

In case you want to see the issue that occurred after `pod install`, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427772/mdfinternationalization-errors-after-trying-to-submit-the-project-to-the-app-sto

Comment: May need to do an Xcode build to update the local Xcode module cache.

Comment: Note that Git is not really involved here: Git only clones repositories and lets you manage working trees and local repositories, while your issue is that the set of repositories you need is changing as you switch from one commit to another. I don't use Xcode but it's possible that the Apple setup needs you to have Xcode run Git so that Xcode can also run other commands to invalidate caches that those other commands use. (This would be annoying and ... quite typical.)